# Code for view, and module name in path besides node id

Tags: views, 7

I am using this snip Stefan Lehmann gave me [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2509906) to have a different image based on node, problem is it works fine with the id, but a couple of the nodes are views, and one is contact, how do I declare those?

```
<?php 
$node = menu_get_object();
$menu_image = 'arrow_home.png';
if (!empty($node)) {
  $images = array(2 => 'arrow_home.png', 3 => 'arrow_formazione.png', 4 => 'arrow_workshop.png', 5 => 'arrow_raccontabito.png');
  $menu_image = isset($images[$node->nid]) ? $images[$node->nid] : $menu_image;
}
?>
<div class="fz-menu-bg">
<img src="/sites/all/themes/business/images/fz/<?php print $menu_image; ?>" />  
</div>
```

This is the structure:

- example.com/node/2 <<< snip ok
- example.com/node/3 <<< snip ok
- example.com/node/4 <<< snip ok
- example.com/node/**gallery <<< view name/path - what code do I need**
- example.com/node/**contact <<< contact module - what code do I need**

Thank you

Comment: you don't need to add 'solved' to the title. Once an answer is acceptable, you can `accept` it by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer, this will tell the community that it has been solved. Even if you are unable to select it yet, anyone reading the question and answer should understand if the existing answers are suitable

Answer (score 0):

In that same block of code, can do an arg() check.

```
$node = menu_get_object(); 
$menu_image = 'arrow_home.png'; 
if (!empty($node)) { 
  $images = array(2 => 'arrow_home.png', 3 => 'arrow_formazione.png', 4 => 'arrow_workshop.png', 5 => 'arrow_raccontabito.png'); 
  $menu_image = isset($images[$node->nid]) ? $images[$node->nid] : $menu_image; 
} 
if (arg(1) == 'gallery') {
  $menu_image = 'arrow_gallery.png';
} 
elseif (arg(1) == 'contact') { 
  $menu_image = 'arrow_contact.png';
}
```

Note: This will only work as long as the URL structure stays the same.

Also, this code depends on where you are preprocessing the image. If you are using `template_preprocess_node()` the above will not work because those two pages, even though they are located at the node path, are not nodes.

Comment: Thank you. Do I integrate that like this?
<?php 
$node = menu_get_object();
$menu_image = 'arrow_home.png';
if (!empty($node)) {
  $images = array(2 => 'arrow_home.png', 3 => 'arrow_formazione.png', 4 => 'arrow_workshop.png', 5 => 'arrow_raccontabito.png');
  $menu_image = isset($images[$node->nid]) ? $images[$node->nid] : $menu_image;
}
if (arg(1) == 'gallery) {
 // Code here for the image
}
else (arg(1) == contact) {
 // Other image code here
}
?>

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and editted the snippet above to add your original code.

Comment: Thank you, very kind of you. I just noticed I am unable to come up with the correct code for the image. I tried    if (arg(1) == 'gallery') {
(arrow_gallery.png);
}  and   if (arg(1) == 'gallery') {
$images = (arrow_gallery.png);
}   but when going to example.com/gallery the image shown is arrow_home.png (the one for node 2

Comment: I updated the code to give you the proper menu image variable. Basically what is happening is that you have seta default value for  `$menu_image`, which is the `arrow_home.png`. So with the if/then statements we need to override them. If you are calling arg() it grabs example.com/arg0/arg1/arg2. Thus, in your original structure /node/gallery, arg(1) grabs gallery, but in example.com/gallery, you'll need to use arg(0). Checkout https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry I don't have yet the rep to upvote your answer.